# How to convert Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap()) to Hash Map

Tags: java, collections

We have a Interface that returns HashMap .

Now due to thread safty we have synchronized our Map using

Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

Now clients that are using our Interface facing class cast exception since

Collections.synchronizedMap returns a synchronized map  and which can not be cast to hash Map

We have to convert this synchronizedMap back to hash map

Is there any way to convert synchronizedMap returned by

Collections.synchronizedMap() back to hash map.

Comment: They can copy it with `new HashMap<>(map)`, or do they want the original?

Comment: `HashMap<...> map = new HashMap<>();` Create and distribute `Collections.synchronizedMap(map);` as you wish, then, when you need the unsynchronized version, just use the original `map`.

Comment: Not sure it's applicable for your situation, but the bottom line is your interface should return `Map`, not `HashMap`. Your situation is exactly the reason why the `Map` interface exists.

Comment: @aioobe That's all sorts of dangerous, since any access to the HashMap won't be ordered with respect to any actions to the synch'd map. Even if the synch'd map is all writes, and the HashMap all reads, it's still a data race.

Comment: I tried copy but synchronizedMap does not have copy method.
I think i need to use putAll Method

Comment: @yshavit, I interpreted it as if OP wanted to hand out a synchronized version temporarily, and then go back to the original. Using them both concurrently is of course not a good idea.

Comment: Even non-concurrently is not a good idea, unless you're careful about establishing formal happens-before edges at both ends of the handoff.

Comment: Lesson learned: when interacting with third-parties you have no control of, make sure to consume and provide generic interfaces (Map instead of HashMap).

Comment: @yshavit, well of course you would have to. Without a happens before relation you have a data race by definition.

Comment: @aioobe My point is that doing so correctly is tricky, and is certainly not as easy as just wrapping a HashMap in a synchronizedMap for a call or two, and then just using the underlying HashMap directly again. With due respect to the OP, if they're asking a question like this, they probably shouldn't be working in the dark corners of the JMM.

Answer (score 3):

If copying is acceptable (that is, you don't need subsequent writes to the synchronized map to be reflected in the returned map), just use HashMap's [constructor that takes a Map input](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap-java.util.Map-). Make sure to synchronize on the synchronizedMap first, since the copy requires iteration over the map (which must anyways be synchronized).

```
synchronized (map) {
  return new HashMap<>(map);
}
```

The synchronized block is not really optional. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but perhaps it could work in your case: create a class that extends HashMap, but that internally has a synchronized Map. Then, delegate all method calls to your internal map. On the constructors, create a new HashMap, then synchronize it. Something like this:

```
public class SynchronizedHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private Map<K, V> internalMap;

    public SynchronizedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        internalMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>(initialCapacity, loadFactor));
    }

    public SynchronizedHashMap(int initialCapacity) {
        internalMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>(initialCapacity));
    }

    public SynchronizedHashMap() {
        internalMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
    }

    public SynchronizedHashMap(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        internalMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>(m));
    }

    @Override public int size() {
        return internalMap.size();
    }

    @Override public boolean isEmpty() {
        return internalMap.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override public boolean containsKey(Object o) {
        return internalMap.containsKey(o);
    }
    ...
}
```

And remember, that's why you should be coding for interfaces, not to concrete implementations. Your interface should return a Map, and your client should consume a Map, without knowledge about *which* Map it is.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be ok :

```
        Map hashMap = new HashMap();
        Map syncMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(hashMap);
        HashMap m = new HashMap(syncMap);
```

Comment: Thanks Guys , Both of you are correct and I am following this approach,

Comment: This one actually isn't correct. It'll compile, and it'll work _most_ of the time -- but it's not thread-safe, and there's a good chance you'll be hit by a bug. Worse still, it'll be a bug that's hard to reproduce and find. Thread-safety bugs are notoriously hard to track down; the thing to do is to be careful not to write them in the first place.